# Why $\beta^+$ radioactivity is possible while lifetime of proton is expected to be infinite?

Tags: particle-physics, radioactivity

In the Standard Model, protons are considered to have an infinite lifetime.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton#Stability
"The spontaneous decay of free protons has never been observed, and protons are therefore considered stable particles according to the Standard Model."

Now, according to wikipedia about $\beta^+$ decays,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay

the $\beta^+$ decay "may be considered as the decay of a proton inside the nucleus to a neutron" : $p\rightarrow n + e^+ + \nu_e$

Does it mean that there is really this decay that happens ? if so, how is that compatible with the fact that the lifetime of proton is expected to be infinite.

How could the fundamental law of authorized decay/forbidden decay be different inside the nucleus and outside nucleus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isolated proton can't undergo $p\to n+e^++\nu_e$; in its rest frame, energy would be created. But a proton in [a suitable larger nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission#Positron-emitting_isotopes) can so decay; the rest of the nucleus responds [in a complicated way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) that ensure the conservation of energy and momentum.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you know why $p\rightarrow n+ e^+ + \nu_e$ involve creation of energy ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian The left-hand side only has $m_pc^2$ in the proton's rest frame, which isn't even enough for a neutron, let alone a positron and neutrino besides.

Comment: An enormous thanks for having shared your knowledge. Everything is clear.